# Filtering curl output using html tags

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to filter a curl output which is an imdb movie page for the title of the movie, movie run time, imdb rating and release year. I'm not able to use pattern matching to filter out data as the pattern is not consistent. Can you help me with filtering the curl command output by html tags? I'm providing two outputs for sample.

Output 1:

oMovies
* Release_CalendarDVD_&*Blu-ray_ReleasesTop_250_MoviesMost_Popular
MoviesBrowse_Movies_by_GenreTop_Box_OfficeShowtimes*&*TicketsIn
TheatersComing_SoonMovie_NewsIndia_Movie_Spotlight
oTV Shows
* What's_on_TV*&*StreamingTop_250_TV_ShowsMost_Popular_TV_ShowsBrowse
TV_Shows_by_GenreTV_NewsIndia_TV_Spotlight
oWatch
* What_to_WatchLatest_TrailersIMDb_OriginalsIMDb_PicksIMDb_Podcasts
oAwards & Events
* OscarsBest_Picture_WinnersBest_Picture_WinnersEmmysSTARmeter_AwardsSan
Diego_Comic-ConNew_York_Comic-ConSundance_Film_FestivalToronto_Int'l
Film_FestivalAwards_CentralFestival_CentralAll_Events
oCelebs
* Born_TodayMost_Popular_CelebsMost_Popular_CelebsCelebrity_News
oCommunity
* Help_CenterContributor_ZonePolls
For_Industry_Professionals
⁰
All
⁰
* All
* Titles
* TV Episodes
* Celebs
* Companies
* Keywords
* Advanced_Search
[q                   ]
Watchlist
Sign_In
EN
⁰
* Fully supported
* English (United States)
* Partially_supported
* FranÃ§ais (Canada)
* FranÃ§ais (France)
* Deutsch (Deutschland)
* à¤¹à¤¿à¤à¤¦à¥ (à¤­à¤¾à¤°à¤¤)
* Italiano (Italia)
* PortuguÃªs (Brasil)
* EspaÃ±ol (EspaÃ±a)
* EspaÃ±ol (MÃ©xico)
****** Mixed Up ******
* 19151915
IMDb RATING
7.5/10
20
YOUR RATING
Rate
* Cast*&_crew
* User_reviews
* Trivia
* IMDbPro
All topics
ShortComedy
Add_a_plot_in_your_language
IMDb RATING
7.5/10
20
YOUR RATING
Rate
* Stars
o Robert_Bolder(archive footage)
o Charles_Chaplin(archive footage)
o Chester_Conklin(archive footage)
* Stars
o Robert_Bolder(archive footage)
o Charles_Chaplin(archive footage)
o Chester_Conklin(archive footage)
See_production,*box_office*&_company_info
* 1User_review
See_production,*box_office*&*company_info
See_more_at_IMDbPro
**** Photos ****
Add_photo
*****Top_cast*****
Edit
[Robert Bolder]
Robert_Bolder
[Charles Chaplin]
Charles_Chaplin
[Chester Conklin]
Chester_Conklin
Norma_Nichols
[Ben Turpin]
Ben_Turpin
[Leo White]
Leo_White
* All_cast*&*crew
* See_more_cast_details_at_IMDbPro
**** Storyline ****
Edit
* Add_full_plot
* Add_synopsis
* Genres
o Short
o Comedy
* Parents guide
o Add_content_advisory
**** Did you know ****
Edit
* Trivia
This film is a compilation put together by Keystone to capitalize on the
"Chaplin craze" that was at its peak in 1915. It is made up of clips from
Chaplin's Keystone comedies, edited together in such a way to tell a
"new" story.
* Connections
Edited from Those_Love_Pangs (1914)
*****User_reviews1*****
Review
Top review
The Keystone Film Company
Having moved to Essanay Films where he could write, direct and appear in his
own films, Chaplin acted in this film by the Keystone Film Company which was
delayed in being released. His films were being churned out on a weekly basis,
and appeared in a total of 35 short films in 1914 alone.
helpfulâ¢1
8
* Single-Black-Male
* Dec 31, 2003
**** Details ****
Edit
* Release_date
o October_1915*(United_States)
* Country of origin
o United_States
* Official site
o Instagram
* Languages
o None
o English
* Production_company
o Keystone_Film_Company
* See_more_company_credits_at_IMDbPro
*****Technical_specs*****
Edit
* Color
o Black_and_White
* Sound mix
o Silent
* Aspect ratio
o 1.33 : 1
**** Contribute to this page ****
Suggest an edit or add missing content
* IMDb_Answers:_Help_fill_gaps_in_our_data
* Learn_more_about_contributing
Edit_page
**** More to explore ****
[View list]
List
The_Best_Movies_and_Shows_to_Watch_in_April
See_the_full_list
[View list]
List
2022_TV_Guide:_The_Best_Shows_Coming_This_Year
See_the_full_list
**** Recently viewed ****
Please enable browser cookies to use this feature.Â Learn_more.
Get_the_IMDb_App
* Get_the_IMDb_App
* Help
* Site_Index
* IMDbPro
* Box_Office_Mojo
* IMDb_Developer
* Press_Room
* Advertising
* Jobs
* Conditions_of_Use
* Privacy_Policy
* Interest-Based_Ads
Â© 1990-2022 by IMDb.com, Inc.

Comment: Providing a sample input and example output would help a ton.

Comment: Use the proper tool for the job, like an html parser (i.e. https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

Comment: @Inogueir, I've added a sample output. Thank you

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, I have to use bash and not python for this task. Can you please point me to resources in bash? Thank you

Comment: @vishal_P there's no way you can reliably parse HTML with bash

Comment: I'd try to figure out if IMDb has a way to get that information as JSON instead of HTML. Then use `jq` or the like to extract what you want